# Show tabular under <page>. Notebook doesnt work

Tags: python, odoo-10

anyone. I want to make table under the  like order lines in sales. But now, I will add like that in payroll module. When I'm using , my new page doesnot show. I used odoo v10. Here my code :

my .py

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
class PayrollOrder(models.Model):
_inherit = 'hr.payslip'

 gaji_pokok = fields.Integer(string="Gaji Pokok")
 t_lembur = fields.Integer(string="Tunjangan Lembur")
```

Here my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record id="view_hr_payslip_inherit_form_extended" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">hr.payslip.inherit.form</field>
<field name="model">hr.payslip</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_payroll.view_hr_payslip_form" />
<field name="arch" type="xml">

<xpath expr="//page[1]" position="after">
     <form string="tes_table" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
         <notebook>
             <page string="Pendapatan Karyawan">
                 <separator string="Tes Hasil"/>
                     <group col="4">
                         <tree colspan="4" nolabel="1" string="Tunjangan Gaji">
                             <field name="gaji_pokok"/>
                             <field name="t_lembur"/>
                         </tree>
                     </group>
                 </page>
             </notebook>
         </form>
     </xpath>
 </record>
```

Anyone can help me please about this?

Comment: You need to set up a [`One2many` field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-fields-relational) to link the `hr.payslip` to another model (you may need to create a new one) such as `hr.payslip.line`. Look at Odoo's core code by comparing `sale.order` and `sale.order.line`. The `sale.order.line` is linked to the `sale.order` by the `order_id` field. The `sale.order` can access its `sale.order.line` by the `order_line` field.

Comment: okay, thanks for your answer. Now it works

Comment: Glad it was helpful! You should post your final solution as an answer for any future visitors with a similar questions.